# postgresql database password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to build a rails app and deploy it to heroku, I'm very new to all of this, and I'm following this [Getting started on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails6#view-logs) I first installed heroku and postgresql, in the command line (windows 10) I run this command `heroku login` then `rails new weather --database=postgresql` then I cd into the weather folder, I run `rails db:create` and I get this error `` fe_sendauth: no password supplied Couldn't create 'weather_development' database. Please check your configuration. rails aborted! PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied bin/rails:4:in `<main>' Tasks: TOP => db:create `` 
what to configure, and where are the configurations files?

Comment: This is referring to the lack of credentials in your `database.yml`.  Your local PostgreSQL DB requires a username and password to use it.

Comment: @coderhs This is the code in ```database.yml``` regarding the username and password ```production:
  <<: *default
  database: weather_production
  username: weather
  password: <%= ENV['WEATHER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Installing postgresql locally on Ubuntu:

gemfile:

`gem "pg"`

console:

```
sudo apt install postgresql libpq-dev
sudo su postgres
createuser --interactive --pwprompt
username
password
```

start server:

```
rails db:create db:migrate
rails s
```

don't have `sqlite` and `pg` installed in one app at the same time.

if you have a postgresql database working in development environment, it will work in heroku for sure.

after pushing to heroku, don't forget to run `heroku run rails db:migrate`

Comment: Thanks but I mentioned that I'm using windows